# Django Filtering by FK more than x value count

Tags: django

I hope you can see what I'm trying to do with the following line...

```
Group.objects.filter(contacts.count>1)
```

I want to filter and only get groups that have more than 1 related contact.

Above will not work so how should it be done?

Thanks

**models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='contacts')


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Group.objects.annotate(c=Count('contacts')).filter(c__gt=1)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) on Annotation and Aggregation. See also [Filtering on Annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations).